# Which Python libraries exist for extracting useful data from tweets?

Tags: python, twitter

I've found this: https://github.com/dryan/twitter-text-py based on Matt Sanford's Ruby code however it hasn't been updated since June 2010.

I've also found this: https://github.com/BonsaiDen/twitter-text-python based on Matt Sanford's Java code.

Are there any others?

Comment: This is rather ambiguous. What constitutes "useful data"? How is this different from asking "Which Python libraries exist for extracting useful data from arbitrary text?" ?

Comment: You just answered your own question, IMHO. And twitter-text-py is updated 7 months ago.

Comment: I am the current maintainer for twitter-text-python. The actively-developed version is now located at: [https://github.com/edburnett/twitter-text-python](https://github.com/edburnett/twitter-text-python)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a list of libraries: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries .

Comment: The question concerns parsing the content of tweets returned by the API, not a library for accessing the API as covered in this link.